# How to implement 'server side' Stripe code into Android App using SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, stripe-payments

I was able to create a token using Stripes [Android Walkthrough](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android#credit-card-form).  But now I would like to create a customer and eventually a charge which they show how to do on your server [here](https://stripe.com/docs/charges). But I am using SQLite for my database as this app is only going to be used by a few people and going to loaded to a single tablet by me only.  So my question is can I create a customer in my application without having to build an entire Server Side backend into my app?

Here is the code where I create my token, now with that token I'd like to create a customer: (Ignore the messiness of the app, sorry, final app will be more clean just trying to see if I can get it to work)

```
package com.zeuspwr.zeuspower;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.stripe.android.*;
import com.stripe.android.model.Card;
import com.stripe.android.model.Token;
import com.stripe.android.Stripe;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class newUser extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText fNameh;
    EditText lNameh;
    EditText emailh;
    EditText phoneNumh;
    EditText pinh;
    EditText cardNumberh;
    EditText cardCVCh;
    Spinner cardExpMonthh;
    Spinner cardExpYearh;
    String fname;
    String lname;
    String email;
    String phonenum;
    String pin;
    String cardNumber;
    String cardCVC;
    Integer cardExpMonth;
    Integer cardExpYear;
    String stripetok;
    Card cardNew;

    String cardExpMonthStr;
    String cardExpYearStr;

    private static final String PUBLISHABLE_KEY = "pk_test_iUVdhdvJuurqSxIlXpzq32LS";
    UserDBHelper newUserr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_user);

        newUserr = new UserDBHelper(newUser.this);

        fNameh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fNameNew);
        lNameh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lNameNew);
        emailh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailNew);
        phoneNumh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNew);
        pinh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pinNew);
        cardNumberh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cardNumNew);
        cardCVCh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cvcNew);
        cardExpMonthh = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.monthNew);
        cardExpYearh = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yearNew);


        ImageButton createNewUser = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.createNew);



        createNewUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                fname = fNameh.getText().toString();
                lname = lNameh.getText().toString();
                email = emailh.getText().toString();
                phonenum = phoneNumh.getText().toString();
                pin = pinh.getText().toString();
                cardNumber = cardNumberh.getText().toString();
                cardCVC = cardCVCh.getText().toString();
                cardExpMonthStr = cardExpMonthh.getSelectedItem().toString();
                cardExpYearStr = cardExpYearh.getSelectedItem().toString();
                cardExpMonth = Integer.valueOf(cardExpMonthStr);
                cardExpYear = Integer.valueOf(cardExpYearStr);

                cardNew = new Card(
                        cardNumber,
                        cardExpMonth,
                        cardExpYear,
                        cardCVC
                );

                if(cardNew.validateCard() & cardNew.validateCVC()) {
                    final Stripe stripe = new Stripe();
                    stripe.createToken(cardNew, PUBLISHABLE_KEY, new TokenCallback() {
                        public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                            // TODO: Send Token information to your backend to initiate a charge


                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Token created: " + token.getId(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        public void onError(Exception error) {
                            Log.d("Stripe", error.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    });

                }

                else{
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Token not made!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



                /*Intent retPage = new Intent(BorroworReturn.this, returno.class);

                startActivity(retPage);*/
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to do any of this in your Android application as those calls require your Secret API key. You should never have the Secret API key in your Android application otherwise an attacker could get his hands on it and then create charges, refunds or transfers on your behalf.

What you need to do here is create a card token first (which you did) and then send it to your server where you will create the charge or the customer using your Secret key. Nothing of this can happen in your Android application.

You can refer to this other question: [the correct way of sending a stripe token with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39104080/1606729) to check some Android code on how to send a token to your server.

Server-side, you'll want to retrieve the token and then use it to create a [Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) or a [Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer).